# RSTP EDGE Port behavior understanding

Tags: forwarding, stp

I have some problems for understand RSTP. I read **IEEE Std 802.1D™- 2004** and have some questions.
In **17.3** I see this notes: Each *Edge Port* transitions directly to the *Forwarding Port State*, since there is no possibility of it participating in a loop.

But I don't see it in state machine schemes.

**17.30 Port State Transition state machine** doesn't have direct way for transit from *Discarding state* to *Forwarding state* with out *Learning state*.

and in **17.29.3 Designated Port states** I don't see this behavior for *Edge port*.
port with true *operEdge* first go to *DESIGNATED_LEARN* and then go to  *DESIGNATED_FORWARD*.

Can you help me understand this moments?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to **Figure 17-22─Designated port role transtions** in IEEE Std 802.1D™- 2004; **17.29.3 Designated Port states** at page 176 as shown below.

In the case of an edge port (i.e,., **operEdge == TRUE**), when the link is up, the port state will transit from DESIGNATED_DISCARD to DESIGNATED_LEARN as the RED line and the condition 1. shown in below figure, and then it will move to DESIGNATED_FORWARD in the blink of an eye as the condition 2 and the BLUE line. It skips the fdWhile (forward delay) time.

Therefore, the note says that  Each Edge Port transitions directly to the Forwarding Port State, since there is no possibility of it participating in a loop.

[image: Figure 17-22─Designated port role transtions]